# How to get checked values into an array for Angular Template Driven Form (ngModel)

Tags: angular, angular-ngmodel, angular-forms

I'm attempting to use template driven forms, binding to a model in the html to a new instance of lets say **Person**. I've been unsuccessful in creating a proper binding for checkboxes to a single array property on my model.

The idea is data will come from an api or other source, dynamically render checkboxes via `*ngFor` and bind what is selected to the **Person** models property which would be an array of numbers. For example:

```
class Person {
  firstName: string;
  someCheckboxPropList: number[];
}
```

and data could be anything really

```
const dynamicData = [
  { name: 'name1', value: 1 },
  { name: 'name2', value: 2 }
];
```

my expected output would be something along the lines of  `[ 1, 2 ]` if both values where to be checked and if only the second was checked `[ 2 ]`.

Here's a sample of what the PersonComponent.ts file might look like

```
@Component({ ... })
export class PersonComponent {

    submitted = false;

    model = new Person();

    constructor() { }

    onSubmit(form) {
        this.submitted = true;
        console.log(form);
    }

}
```

And where I'm at with the components html file.

```
<form (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(form)" #form="ngForm">

    <input type="text" [(ngModel)] name="person.firstName">

    <div *ngFor="let dataItem of dynamicData" >
        <input 
            type="checkbox"
            ngModel
            name="dynamicData"
            [value]="dataItem.value">
        <label>{{dataItem.name}}</label>
    </div>

</form>
```

This does not work (and is sample code anyway).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the idea is have two things: Person and PersonForm, so,e.g

```
person={firstName:"Jessy",props:[1,2]
//but 
personForm={firstName:"Jessy",props:[true,true]
```

So, make two functions

```
  createForm(person) {
    return {
      firstName: person.firstName,
      props: this.dynamicData.map(x => person.props.indexOf(x.value) >= 0)
    }
  }
  retrieveData(personForm) {
    let props: number[] = [];
    personForm.props.forEach((v, index) => {
      if (v)
        props.push(this.dynamicData[index].value)
    }
    )
    return {
      firstName: personForm.firstName,
      props: props
    }
  }
```

Well, we have already all we need. When we received a person, create a personForm that it's the data we change in the form. In submit simply call to retrieveData to get the value of person.

When we have a person create a personForm,e.g.

```
this.service.getPerson().subscribe(person=>
    {
       this.personForm=createForm(person)
    }
)
```

Our form

```
<form *ngIf="personForm" (submit)="sendData(personForm)">
  <input name="firtName" [(ngModel)]="personForm.firstName">
  <div *ngFor="let item of dynamicData;let i=index">
  <input name="{{'prop'+i}}" 
         type="checkBox" [(ngModel)]="personForm.props[i]">{{item.name}}
  </div>
  <button>Submit</button>
</form>
{{personForm|json}}<br/>
{{retrieveData(personForm)|json}}
```

And our sendData function

```
sendData(personForm)
{
    console.log(this.retrieveData(personForm))
}
```

I make a [simple stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hnxdkj?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

**Update**

NOTE:We can use the spred operator to asing properties, so

```
  createForm(person) {
    return {
      ...person, //All the properties of person, but
      props: this.dynamicData.map(x => person.props.indexOf(x.value) >= 0)
    }
  }
  retrieveData(personForm) {
    let props: number[] = [];
    personForm.props.forEach((v, index) => {
      if (v)
        props.push(this.dynamicData[index].value)
    }
    )
    return {
      ..personForm, //all the properties of personForm, but
      props: props
    }
  }
```

NOTE2: In a "real world" the persons goes from a service. Consider the idea that service get/received the "personForm" and put the functions to transform in the service

```
//in service
getPerson()
{
    return this.httpClient.get("...").map(res=>this.createForm(res))
}
savePerson(personForm)
{
    return this.httpClient.post("...",this.retrieveData(personForm))
}
```

Comment: I'm going to work with this for a bit thanks for your insight, if It works i'll mark your response as the answer :)

Comment: Thanks @Eliseo for this :) I've cleaned up the demo you provided and I understand how the solution works https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-fl7m2x

Answer (score 1):

If we want, we can make a custom Form control.

In this case we need as input, a source, and the cols of the source -the first will be the key, and the second one the text that appears.

I make a [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ytgavk?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

the .html will be

```
  <check-box-group name="props" [(ngModel)]="person.props"
      [source]="dynamicData" cols="value,name" >
  </check-box-group>
```

the component it's a tipical custom form control

```
@Component({
  selector: 'check-box-group',
  template: `
      <div class="form-check" *ngFor="let item of source;let i=index">
        <input class="form-check-input" id="{{_name+''+i}}"
             type="checkBox" [ngModel]="_selectedItems[i]"
             (ngModelChange)="setValue($event,i)">
        <label class="form-check-label" for="{{_name+''+i}}">
              {{item[_col]}}
        </label>
      </div>
  `,
  providers: [
    {
      provide: NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR,
      useExisting: forwardRef(() => CheckBoxGroupComponent),
      multi: true
    }
  ]
})
export class CheckBoxGroupComponent implements ControlValueAccessor {

  @Input() source;
  @Input()
  set cols(value:string){ //cols is a string separated by commas
                          //e.g. "value,text", the "key" will be "value" and show the text
    let _cols=value.split(',')
    this._key = _cols[0];
    this._col = _cols[1]
  }
  _selectedItems: any[] = [];
  _key: string;
  _col: string;
  _name:string="";
  onChange;
  onTouched;

  constructor(el:ElementRef) { 
    let name=el.nativeElement.getAttribute('name')
    this._name=name?name:"ck";
  }
  writeValue(value: any[]): void {
    this._selectedItems = this.propsToBoolean(value);
  }

  registerOnChange(fn: any): void {
    this.onChange = fn;
  }

  registerOnTouched(fn: any): void {
    this.onTouched = fn;
  }

  setDisabledState(isDisabled: boolean): void {
  }
  setValue(value: boolean, index: number) {
    this._selectedItems[index] = value;
    this.onChange(this.booleanToProps(this._selectedItems));

  }

  propsToBoolean(props): any[] {
    console.log(props);
    return props ? this.source.map((x: any) => props.indexOf(x[this._key]) >= 0)
      : this.source.map(x => false);

  }
  booleanToProps(propsBoolean: boolean[]) {
    let props: any[] = [];
    if (propsBoolean) {
      propsBoolean.forEach((item, index) => {
        if (item)
          props.push(this.source[index][this._key])
      })
    }
    return props;

  }

}
```

**Update:** add validations

when we have a custom form component and we want to make a "validation" we have two options, make the validation outside the component or make a validation inside the component. For the second option we must to add as provider provide: NG_VALIDATORS,,

```
{
  provide: NG_VALIDATORS,
  useExisting: forwardRef(() => CheckBoxGroupComponent),
  multi: true,
}
```

And add a function validate

```
validate(control: AbstractControl): ValidationErrors | null{
    ...your logic here.., e.g.
    if (!this._selectedItems.find(x=>x))
       return {error:"you must select one option at last"}

    return null
  }
```

Well, there're a more thing we must to do that is decide when our custom control are touched. Remember that a control is touched when lost the focus after received it. we can do it in a (blur) of our checkbox (or enclose the control in a div with tabindex=0)

```
 <input type="checkbox" .... (blur)="onTouched()">
```

The last step is make give an error or not is we add an attribute to the control. I like that if we add an attribute isRequired, check the error else not. So we add a new property _isRequired and, in contructor check if has the attribute

```
 constructor(el:ElementRef) { 
    let name=el.nativeElement.getAttribute('name');
    this._isRequired=el.nativeElement.getAttribute('isRequired')!=null?true:false;
    this._name=name?name:"ck"; //<--this is necesary for give value to
                               //for="..." in label
    }
```

And our validation take account of this

```
  validate(control: AbstractControl): ValidationErrors | null{
    if (!this._isRequired)
      return null;
    ....
  }
```

NOTE: I updated the custom control (and we add a propertie [customClass])

Comment: I have a related question to this, Since we enabled two way binding on our custom control, how would we have validation work between the inner model vs the outer binding?  I've been able to add things like required and the model responds correctly but I want to set that up inside of the components template not on the use of it. any ideas?

Comment: I'am not sure what do you want. when we have a custom form component and we want to make a "validation" we have two options, make the validation outside the component or make a validation inside the component. I updated my answer and the stackblitz