# Not getting the values of multiple check boxes in Angular Reactive Forms

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

I'm creating Angular Reactive forms and I have added multiple checkboxes there. I want to get the user selected values to an array. Form is generating from JSON data. When user clicks a checkbox it's adding to array. When user clicks the other checkbox it only shows the latest one and the previous selected value has not there. This is what I tried.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/github-ejwhnx
(You can check stackblitz console to selected value)

Appreciate if anyone can give a support to fix this issue.

Comment: did you peek into the DOM? Looks like your for loops are not creating unique inputs.

Comment: @coderaizer, I think you're building the house by the roof. when we want to work with ReactiveForms, we must have clear two things: 1.-The form, 2.-How show it. Really you has no form (just write in your form-main-component.html){{quizForm?.value|json}}

Comment: @Eliseo - Thanks for the kind reply. I'm new to Reactive forms. This is what I'm getting { "undefined": null } . Could you please help

Comment: @David Aguirre- I tried adding unique values , but getting the same issue

Answer (score 0):

Coderaizer. You must have clear what do you want to obtain. let me show an example:

Imagine you want to obtain some like (remember that it's an example: You decided what do you want to obtain)

```
data=[
{id:1004,answer:[100401,100402]},
{id:1005,answer:[100503]},
{id:1006,answer:[100603,100606]}
]
```

other example can be obtain only [100401,100402,100503,100603,100606] or even a string "100401,100402,100503,100606,100606"

Well, really the things are not so easy. When we have "checkBox", the checkbox only has two posibles values: true or false, so our object becomes in some like

```
data=[
{id:1004,answer:[true,true]},
{id:1005,answer:[false,false,true]},
{id:1006,answer:[false,false,true,false,false,true]}
]
```

you can see a discussion in this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54117854/how-to-get-checked-values-into-an-array-for-angular-template-driven-form-ngmode/54118915#54118915) (at the end there're a custom FormControl to manage check-box-list)

With the same example in mind, in your component inject formBuilder in the constructor

```
constructor(private fb:FormBuilder){}
```

And create the form in the ngOnInit(). At first with data -forget the json for the moment-

```
  ngOnInit() {
    this.myForm = new FormArray([
      this.fb.group({
        id: 1004,
        answers: new FormArray([new FormControl(true), new FormControl(true)])
      }),
      this.fb.group({
        id: 1005,
        answers: new FormArray([new FormControl(false),new FormControl(false),new FormControl(true)])
      }),
    ])
  }
```

And our .html like

```
  <div *ngFor="let question of myForm.controls" >
    <div [formGroup]="question">
      <input formControlName="id">
      <div formArrayName="answers">
        <div *ngFor="let item of question.get('answers').controls;let i=index">
            <input type="checkbox" [formControlName]="i">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
{{myForm?.value|json}}
```

Now it's the moment to think in our .json. See that our .json sirve to create the form and to show the options in our form

```
  ngOnInit() {
    let group:FormGroup[]=[]
    this.JSON.forEach(x=>{
       group.push(this.fb.group({
         id:x.id,
         answers:new FormArray(x.answers.map(x=>new FormControl(false)))
       }))
    })
    this.myForm = new FormArray(group)
  }
```

And "decorate" our .html to show the options

```
  <div *ngFor="let question of myForm.controls;let j=index" >
    {{JSON[j].question}}
    <div [formGroup]="question">
      <input formControlName="id">
      <div formArrayName="answers">
        <div *ngFor="let item of question.get('answers').controls;let i=index">
            <input type="checkbox" [formControlName]="i">{{JSON[j].answers[i].answer}}
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Well, you has component to show the form, try to see "what is what" to adjust the @Inputs()